# a problem of linking external libraries

Tags: ros, target-link-libraries, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I encountered a problem while linking a ROS program against some external libraries. I am trying to link my ROS program against Xenomai libraries. To make sure Xenomai libraries have been successfully installed in my OS (Ubuntu 10.10), I built a simple program (non-ROS) with gcc like this:

```
gcc -I/usr/xenomai/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D__XENO__ -Wall -pipe -lnative -L/usr/xenomai/lib -lxenomai -lpthread -lrtdk hellworld.c -o helloworld
```

No problems arise here, and I got the executable.

To build my ROS programs (take as an example the tutorial program at the [ROS website](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) ), I add the following commands to CMakeLists.txt:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
include_directories(/usr/xenomai/include)
add_definitions(-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D__XENO__)
rosbuild_add_compile_flags(listener -Wall -pipe)
link_directories(/usr/xenomai/lib)
target_link_libraries(listener native xenomai pthread rtdk)
```

That says, I want to link the “listener” node against some Xenomai libraries, like “native”, “xenomai”, etc. However, when I rosmake’d the whole package, I got this error:

```
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/listener
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnative
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxenomai
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems rosbuild did not search libraries in “/usr/xenomai/lib” which is supposed to specified by `link_directories(/usr/xenomai/lib)`. Did I miss something to tell rosbuild to search libraries in “/usr/xenomai/lib”?

With many thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11294/a-problem-of-linking-external-libraries/) by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some googling, I found [this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2005-September/007243.html). I think I can now answer the problem myself: It turned out that I need to place `link_directories(/usr/xenomai/lib)` before `rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)`, that is,

```
link_directories(/usr/xenomai/lib)
rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
include_directories(/usr/xenomai/include)
add_definitions(-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D__XENO__)
rosbuild_add_compile_flags(listener -Wall -pipe)
target_link_libraries(listener native xenomai pthread rtdk)
```

Is this a bug, or a restriction of CMake? Is it documented somewhere?

---

Originally posted by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) with karma: 76 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on 2011-09-26**:
Is this requirement of CMake documented somewhere? I came from gcc, and the order should not cause a compilation error in gcc.

**Comment by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on 2011-09-26**:
In the problematic CMakeLists.txt, I tried to add "/usr/xenomai/lib" to the search path by adding "link_directories(/usr/xenomai/lib)". However, I added this command after "rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)", and it turned out that I need to reverse the order of these two commands.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-25**:
/usr/xenomai/lib is not a default location to look for libraries, so you have to add it to the search path.

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2013-05-06**:
I am going to use one external library (VISION - a private lib) with my ROS package (which already uses opencv). Shall I use the external library, by just including the above lines? Here I didn't understand the last three lines - add_definitions, rosbuild_add_compile_flags and target_link_libraries?